# UUID is saving differently for the same person in Minecraft bungeeCord Network

Tags: uuid, minecraft, bungeecord

The bungeeCord worked perfectly last week, but in the last 2 days I'm receiving some errors. While I'm switching between 2 different internal servers, In one of them it writes the correct UUID while in the other one it randomizes it, I checked on Name MC and UUID MC to check if the UUID is registered, but only one of them is.

The problem starts when all my data goes through my database that's based on MySQL. MySQL differentiates between players using their UUID, and brings them their correct data using their UUID. But while the same player has 2 different UUID's in 2 different servers. And when he logs in to the other server, it doesn't save the data properly.

namemc-1:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUIBi.png)

namemc-2:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUUl6.png)

Mysql:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwu04.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason for this magic is the `online-mode` config variable and setted be to `false` on sub server. This problem can be found in multiple discussions:

https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/bungeecord-uuid-issues.313639/

Comment: Thank you for your time!        The problem was the spigot.xml config.